# Visual Studio 2015 Apache Cordova App won't build, update 3 q.js Failed to run "ant -version" check_reqs.js MSB3073

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio 2015 Apache Cordova App won't build. I installed update 3 and it was working fine for several hours. While debugging, it started crashing and automatically restarting. After several restarts, started getting:

q.js throw e. Failed to run "ant -version" check_reqs.js MSB3073

Rebuild/clean, restarting VS and rebooting computer didn't help. It went from building to not building without any intervening source code changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Tools --> Options --> Tools for Apache Cordova --> Cordova Tools --> Clear Cordova Cache

I would think that the "Rebuild All" should run "Clean" and that a clean operation should thoroughly clean out all intermediate files. Even better, the build process could notice that an error has occurred in intermediate files, and trigger a "Clear Cordova Cache" operation during the next build. Just a thought.